# WYSIHAT and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysihat

Does anyone have any advice on how to go about installing WYSIHAT in a Rails 3 app?

There's a lot of good information about getting it to work with Rails 2, there's an [engine](https://github.com/80beans/wysihat-engine), and some [decent blog posts](http://jrmehle.com/2009/02/13/wysiwhat-wysihat-part-2/) but they're all slightly dated

Also, I would prefer to use JQuery (or MooTools) over Prototype. Am I better off sticking with jQuery WYSIWIG? I really just need to be able to add simple text formatting and hotlink images

Comment: `wsyihat` is firmly fixed in Prototype. You should look at other options if you would like to use JQuery.

Comment: Maybe we should start a reimplementation using jQuery. *fork*

Comment: Are there any alternatives with WYSIHAT for rails 3? I have similar needs as the OP, but perhaps not the 1337ness to forge my own editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a WYSIHAT jQuery fork: https://github.com/swilliams/jq-wysihat